# A word describing someone's preference to have a lineally/genetically-related child

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I'm looking for a word that effectively conveys an attitude showing a preference for having a child related to oneself ... ie, a lineally/genetically-related child.

In particular, a word that would fit the following example:

- *Michael had a _____ attitude, he wanted children of his own*

and / or possibly a noun form:

- *Michael was a _____ unlike Sam who was a non*-_____

which would be helpful in distinguishing between people that prefer to have their own children and those that are happy to adopt, foster, etc.

I had considered "autogenic" ... "auto" meaning self, and "genic" meaning "produced by" ... and even "progenic" (or "progenetic" possibly) which might work here, "pro-", I take to mean "following" or "in favour of" which in combination with "genic" / "genetic" relates to genetic lineage or heritage. However, I'm not sure I've constructed them appropriately, or whether they're right or not.

Comment: I've never heard a word for this.

Comment: I doubt there is a word for this.  What's wrong with the clear *Michael wants to father his own children*?  I expect OP will tell us what's wrong with it, so amn't making this an answer.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark The phrasing you suggest is clear and what I want to ultimately express but isn't exactly what I want. I should have stipulated it in the question, but I'm looking for a convenient *shorthand* way of referring to this kind of attitude.

Comment: I've tidied this, Tom. // If you can't find a candidate in a dictionary (check several), there's at least a strong possibility that it is unwise to use it and expect people to gather what you mean by it (though this can depend on context). Coining neologisms is certainly possible (new words are constantly added to the lexicon), but until there is a reasonable level of usage and understanding, 'D-I-Y-isms' are off-topic on ELU, which is dedicated to standard usage/s. And 'a progenitorial attitude' might well be taken to mean 'an attitude similar to that held by many forefathers'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ok, thank you. I wasn't aware that this was off-topic, so apologies about that.

Comment: The [Cinderella effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinderella_effect) is the opposite, a bias against step-children and non-blood-relatives.

Comment: @Stuart It's an _extreme_ opposite, rather more than a 'bias against' (three less toys for Harry on his birthday).

Comment: If you accept what HighPerformanceMark suggested as 'clear and what I want to ultimately express', how does that fall short of exactly what you want?

Though you didn't stipulate it, how could looking for a convenient shorthand…' matter?

Comment: Evolutionary biologists say all animals have an innate drive to reproduce their genes, and if they're right, it would be something other than a "preference" or an "attitude" in homo sapiens.

Comment: Further to TimR's Comment, is it unreasonable to point out that the exposition describes the standard viewpoint of all intelligent beings, and the instinctive desire of all others?

How is there any difference between a 'lineally/genetically-related child' or
'children of his own' or just plain 'natural/ordinary…'?

Comment: @TimR Hi, I don't know if I quite understand what you're suggesting. I wouldn't agree that "Evolutionary biologists say all animals have an innate drive to reproduce their genes". Rather, I think they would drop the teliological language, and say that animals have innate drives conducive to reproducing their genes, but not that they are driven to, or wish to produce offspring (if that is what you meant).

Comment: @TimR To explain what I mean further, you may find someone sexually attractive (sexual drive), but that does not entail you wish to have children with them, just that, provided you have unprotected sex with them, such activity will be highly conducive of producing children. This is separate from the desire "to" have children, which is the focus of my question, so apologies, I probably should have added more context about it strictly being related to having children in a "goal-related" sense as opposed to "sexual drive"

Comment: @Robbie Goodman Hi, I don't think i've quite understand what you mean by standard viewpoint. Do you mean that the preference to have a lineally/genetically-related child is the normal (majority) position among people? If so, I'd agree that it is, but that everyone does have this preference, I would not agree. On your point about the instinctive desire, I would say people have "sexual drives" but that this is not "directed" towards reproducing, just that satisfying "sexual desire" is an activity highly conducive to producing children. You can read more in my response to TimR.

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin
To answer your second question, I don't quite know what you conceive of as "natural". I guess you just mean produced without assisted technologies, or something like that? If so,  a "lineally/genetically-related" child could be "natural", but so could an "adopted" child, or at least it's not obvious to me as to how they're "unnatural". Or maybe you mean that "adopting" is unnatural, which also isn't obvious to me whether it's "natural" or "unnatural". I don't know if "natural" just isn't applicable here. I just don't quite understand what you're asking to be honest.

Comment: No-one needs to agree that everyone has a preference for it to be so much the standard viewpoint that no-one questions it,  leaving what you're looking for as far-and-away the oddity.

Contrast your search to that for the term 'analogue clock/watch' which had neither need nor even meaning before digital technology came along. A clock or watch was a clock or watch and discussing the idea of a different name about as meaningful as asking how many angels could dance on the head of a pin.

We use distinguishing terms for what stands out from the norm, not the other way round.

Comment: @TomDotCom  Thanks for the clarification. I can't think of an adjective  that means "having the preference to sire and raise children (in a typical 'nuclear' family)" or one that means "having no desire to sire children but a desire to adopt or foster children".

Comment: traditional attitude and a traditionalist would work here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an adjective but you could use a terse caption:

> wants his own children
>
> willing to adopt/foster children

Using the word "progeny" instead of "children" adds a rather clinical or anthropological tone.

Answer (score -2):

*Progenitorial* is a word with the components you listed that could be understood as having this meaning: *an ancestor in a direct line*.

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/progenitor)]

Comment: A 'progenitorial attitude' might well be taken to mean 'an attitude similar to that held by many forefathers'.